# How to remove Result node in Soap Response?

Tags: soap, xml-serialization

I was provided a wsdl and I am supposed to build a service for it in .NET 2.0. I am to the point of returning a response (after hitting the webservice and getting a reply I am supposed to return an acknowledgement so the third party knows I got the data from their webservice). My problem is I have an extra node in the response I am returning to them. This is the current response I am sending back:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
   <tranId>
     <MethodResult>123321</MethodResult>
   </tranId>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The problem is that they are expecting it to look like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
   <tranId>123321</tranId>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How can I remove the Result tag from the SoapResponse in .NET 2.0? Everything I have been able to find, and the code generated from wsdl.exe when I ran that, has recommended using MessageContract to remove that tag. Unfortunately MessageContract is not available in .NET 2.0. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?  I need to do this as well.